# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-jpa

In the code I have shared here [Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238830/exception-in-thread-restartedmain-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception) I am getting new error. Could you please help me with this.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springLogging3Application': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'factory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in com.spring.main.SpringLogging3Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'getSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in com.spring.main.SpringLogging3Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'springLogging3Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'springLogging3Application' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
```

application.properties

```
server.port=6565

db.driver:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe  
db.username:xxxx  
db.password:xxxx

hibarenate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibarenate.show_sql:true  
hibarenate.hbm2ddl.auto:update
entitymanager.packagesToScan:com.spring.main
```

Updated one:

```
server.port=6565

db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe  
db.username=xxxx 
db.password=xxxx

hibarenate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibarenate.show_sql=true  
hibarenate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
entitymanager.packagesToScan=com.spring.main
```

Comment: Can you share the file application.properties or application.yml?

Comment: @Fatih I have added.

Comment: Are you using a spring profile?

Comment: @Fatih No, I am not using any profile.

Comment: you application file is messed up, properties are separated by equals sign `key=value` pair

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- Do not mix "=" and ":" separator in the application.properties file
- Log the "db.driver" property, it seems empty

Regards.

Comment: Please update new application.porperties which you have tried.

Comment: @silentsudo Added. Updated application.properties

Comment: This is not the solution of my problem. Please don't mark it.

Answer (score 0):

please share and check your xyz-servlet.xml configuration file in which you have define spring spring boot and hibernate information.after seeing your error as i understand that it is your hibernate exception in your xml file check whether you have define or not **DriverClassName** details see below example

> **check this out DB have four property driverClassName, url, username and password**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" name="dataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>**check this property whether you have define or not if not then define it corresponding DB driver name as i have defined my driver details**
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am not doing configuration using XML. I did that with annotation and pasted my properties file above. For complete code please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238830/exception-in-thread-restartedmain-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception